# How FCM knows who will receive upstream message?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app where I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging. And I want to send notification message from my device to other device that are in topic group "teamAndroid". I read on Firebase official site that with this code we send that upstream messages:

```
FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();

fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
.setMessageId(Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet()))
.addData("my_message", "Hello World")
.addData("my_action","SAY_HELLO")
.build());
```

But where in this code we put information about which user we want to send message? How FCM knows where to send that message which is sent by me?

Comment: Check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/notifications and this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging

Answer (score 3):

FCM does not offer a direct device-to-device messaging facility. "Upstream message" here means that the message is being sent from your phone to an app server, which you have to implement.

See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) for more details.

To send a message from one device to another, you send it to your app server from device 1, which in turn sends a downstream message to device 2.

Comment: Thanks, just another question...What is an app server? Is that mine backend API or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is your backend that receives messages from the devices, and sends messages to them, among other things. FCM refers to this as the app server.

Comment: But why then we use FCM when all tasks are done with backend?

Comment: FCM is an efficient method to send small messages from your device to your backend and backend to device. You can implement a backend that uses some communication method to directly communicate with your devices (for example, HTTP, XMPP, MQTT, etc.), but then you will have to manage the connections yourself on the devices as well as the backend. With FCM, this process is simplified.

Comment: Just one more mate...Is it possible that when I send message to app server then backend forward that message to some topic?